# Computer hangs indefinitely when shutting down

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, shutdown, ubuntu-20.04

My pc never shuts down. This started happening 2 days ago. I was using parrot os, and did a dist upgrade. I thought that this could have caused the issue. Basically, my pc hangs at reboot: power down.
I have tried all these below steps to fix the issue

1. adding acpi=force in grub.
2. changing setting in bios for SATA ide to ACHI
3. Pressed the pc power off button
4. Changed the operating system itself from parrot os to ubuntu 20.04
5. Removed CMOS and tried booting and then shuting the pc down
6. removed all the pc components and adding them back again
7. using systemctl poweroff
8. shutdown -h now
9. Tried shuting the pc down in the bios menu itself.
10. Loaded default values from BIOS.

My BIOS is gigabyte H55MS2. I don't have a graphic card. I only have intel i3 processor.

Currently, I cannot shut the pc down without plugging off the main power supply. And the keyboard and mouse lights turn off, but the processor fan keeps running, and the display is still on.

I have have tried everything which looked like would work, but none of them yielded any results.
Any suggestions for fixing would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a shutdown problem similar to this one you are having for the longest while.

Besides searching all over the web for answers and posting to specific or relevant OEM forums, I also reported it to bugzilla.kernel.org back in 12/2018:

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201965

Never had a reply.

Then again this year:

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212443

Still waiting for input from somebody at bugzilla but I'm not holding my breath.

Sifting through all I have read about it, my short summary of what has been happening (for many years now) is this:

- Motherboard BIOS files are not written strictly observing the specifications from the governing bodies.
- They are written to the (much laxer) specifications given to them by Microsoft and the BIOS writers/OEMs accept them because if they do not, their hardware will not be "Windows Certified" which basically means that it will not be sold.
- The Linux kernel people have taken the only possible stance which is to work around these 'quirks' within the kernel so that Linux will boot on most any motherboard but it is short of an uphill battle as the problem is permanent and ongoing.
- As this happens, newer kernels end up revealing old and previously unseen or unreported bugs (probably your case) lurking in reused/rehashed BIOS code inside the libraries used by the usual BIOS OEM crowd ie: Intel, AMI, Phoenix, Award et al.

If you haven't yet, you could try to get a BIOS upgrade from Gigabyte if it is available and see what happens and if it does 'not' fix the problem, report it to them and see what their TS has to say.

Good luck with that, their motherboards probably have no Linux support and will probably send you to talk to A, B or C's chipset manufacturer.

The other option, which I strongly suggest, is to go back to the Linux kernel you were using before the problem arose.

But before doing that, send the Parrot OS kernel maintainers the following files from 'both' installations. ie: the one *with* the problem and the one *without* the problem.

- screenshot (at hang)
- output of `inxi -Fxxxz` (as root)
- dmesg
- acpidump
- syslog

The data will help them see and try to solve the issue and maybe write a patch that may/will/should be eventually reported upstream for a fix in a next/future kernel release.

Sorry but I don't have another solution to offer.
The lesson would be that one should only purchase Linux certified HW.

But I have a Sun Microsystems workstation 'and' the same problem you have, so the lesson is actually lacking in value.

Best,

G.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem too, in dual-boot with windows actually. What worked for me is that I reinstalled the OS by Manual Partitioning and not the recommended one. I configured the boot file to be fat32,and root file to be ext4 along with swap area. Since then I have been able to shutdown and reboot as normally, not hanging indefinitely as it was before. I hope this worked for you guys too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).